# Tooltip arrow does not show the right direction in bootstrap 5 RTL

Tags: tooltip, bootstrap-5

I'm using bootstrap 5 RTL. when I use tooltip, tooltip arrow direction is not toward my element! What should I do?

```
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css" integrity="sha384-gXt9imSW0VcJVHezoNQsP+TNrjYXoGcrqBZJpry9zJt8PCQjobwmhMGaDHTASo9N" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
         var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
         var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
            return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
         })
      });
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="right" title="logout"> //tooltip here
      <i class="fa fa-power-off fa-lg"></i> //power of icon
   </a>
</body>
```

See problem her: [IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jq5d7.png)

Comment: PLease edit your post and include any code you have otherwise the rest of us are just guessing. Thanks Saleh.

Comment: Sorry for that! I added my code!

Comment: It's OK mate don't worry. Best recommend is to take the tour. There is if you like to think of it this way ... a `proper` way to ask questions. It's all explained in the tour. stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: OK so i had a quick look and not 100% sure at the moment but it might be because you are using RTL. Most usually this is a language resource used for languages which go from right to left on a page rather than left to right. Like Arabic for example. Try removing RTL stuff just as a test and see if the tooltip then displays correctly.

Comment: Yes! This problem is just on RTL... Is there a way to fix it?! My whole website uses bootstrap RTL, I can't change it.

Comment: OK got you. Sorry. Should have realised you're using RTL for a reason. If you scroll down this page just about half way there is some things about `placement` and `fallbackplacement` on tooltips.  Clearly your RTL is making that tip appear in reverse but hopefully you can the tip itself can be altered whilst leaving your code in place. 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/tooltips/

Comment: Ok. Thanks alot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: 
I just needed to add `dir="rtl"` attribute to the `<html>` tag. 
css `direction:rtl` wont work!